# Sympy unable to solve system of 3 equations

Tags: python, sympy, solver

So I'm quite new to sympy and I am trying to solve a system of 3 equations. However, `solve` doesn't seem to give me any solution (at least not after 30 minutes of running) and `nonlinsolve` gives me a solution, but only for two of the variables. I have tried to change the domain and the assumption, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I know there is a solution, as Maple has no problem giving me one. What did I miss? Here is my code

```py
import sympy as smp
smp.init_printing()

#Define my symbols with assumptions
v0,L,T,g,h, = smp.symbols('v0,L,T,g,h',real=True,positive=True)
theta = smp.symbols('theta',real=True,domain=smp.Interval(0,smp.pi/2))

#Define my equations
eq1 = v0*smp.cos(theta)*T-L
eq2 = v0*smp.sin(theta)*smp.Rational(1,2)-smp.Rational(1,2)*g*(T*smp.Rational(1,2))**2-h
eq3 = v0*smp.sin(theta)*T-smp.Rational(1,2)*g*(T)**2

#Try to solve with solve (Just hangs)
smp.solve((eq1,eq2,eq3),(v0,theta,T))

#Try to solve with nonlinsolve (Gives everything but theta)
smp.solve((eq1,eq2,eq3),(v0,theta,T))
```

I tried to add domains for the symbols with no luck. I also tried both of these solvers. I tried to add `manual = True` with no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is a difficult one to solve. I assume you want to obtain algebraic expressions of `v0`, theta and T in terms of L, g and h. If you need a numerical solution for given L, g and h you can use `nsolve()`.

I tried to simplify the equations. From the first equation it follows that

`L = v0 * smp.cos(theta) * T`
or

```
smp.cos(theta) = L/(T * v0)
```

You can then use that `sin(x) = + sqrt(1-cos^2(x))` in equations 2 and 3 and substitute `cos(theta)=L/(T * v0)`

That is,

```
v0 * smp.sin(theta) = v0 * smp.sqrt(1-smp.cos(theta)**2) = v0 * smp.sqrt(1-(L/(T * v0)))
```

And in equation (3)
`v0 * smp.sin(theta) * T = v0 * T * smp.sqrt(1-smp.cos(theta)**2) = v0 * T * smp.sqrt(1-(L/(T * v0))`)

And we can subsitute `cos(theta)=alpha in (0,1)`.

```
alpha = smp.symbols('alpha',real=True,domain=smp.Interval(0,1))
eq1 = v0 * alpha * T-L
```

Summarizing, I have rewritten your code as follows:

```
#Define my equations
eq1 = v0 * alpha * T-L
eq2 = v0 * smp.sqrt(1-(L/(T * v0))) * smp.Rational(1,2)-smp.Rational(1,2) * g * (T * smp.Rational(1,2))**2-h
eq3 = v0 * T * smp.sqrt(1-(L/(T * v0))) - smp.Rational(1,2) * g * (T)**2

smp.solve((eq1,eq2,eq3),(v0,alpha,T))
```

This still does not give a solution in reasonable time, but I think you should first check the equations in more detail to find out if there are solutions to this set of equations. smichr shows you can first solve equations 1 and 3 and then substitute the answer in equation 2.

P.S. Your last line of code is actually the same as the final but last line.

Answer (score 0):

With some manual help you can solve this:

```py
>>> from sympy.solvers.solvers import unrad
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import x

# your non-solve code

>>> tv = solve([eq1, eq3], T, v0, dict=True)
>>> y = eq2.subs(tv[0])
>>> unrad(y.rewrite(exp).subs(exp(I*theta),x))[0].as_numer_denom()[0]
```

You will see an expression which is even in powers of `x` and is the product of a monomial in `x**4` and a quartic in `x` (if you factor it). Replace `x**2` with `z` and solve for the three values,

```py
>>> solve(_, z)
[0, (-2*L*sqrt(g)*sqrt(g - 8*h) + I*(L**2 + 16*h**2))/(I*L**2 + 2*L*g - 8*L*h - 16*I*h**2), (2*L*sqrt(g)*sqrt(g - 8*h) + I*(L**2 + 16*h**2))/(I*L**2 + 2*L*g - 8*L*h - 16*I*h**2)]
```

Now solve for the 6 corresponding values of `x`

```py
>>> [solve(x**2 - i, x, dict=True) for i in _]
```

Then solve for the corresponding values of `theta`.

```py
>>> th = [solve(exp(I*theta) - x.subs(j), theta, dict=True) for s in _ for j in s]
```

Substituting these into the solutions (ignoring the empty solution) for `tv` should give you the symbolic solutions:

```py
>>> TV = [Dict(tvi).subs(si) for tvi in tv for s in th for si in s if s]
```

And then collecting all solution variables in one dictionary gives:

```py
sol = []
for li in th: # li lists of dicts
 for i in li: # i dict
  d = i.copy()
  for j in TV: # j Dict
    d.update(j)
    sol.append(d)
```

Many of those are redundant (perhaps because I used both tv solution). There are 6 unique solutions:

```py
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import uniq
>>> u = list(uniq(sol))
>>> len(u), count_ops(u)
(6, 1312)
```

Do you just want numerical solutions for given constants? If so, do those substitutions first and then use `nsolve`.